# Will assigning an event handler to Activity from a fragment create a cyclic reference?

Tags: android, memory, android-fragments, xamarin, xamarin.android

In my Xamarin.Android(Monodroid) application, I have one activity that displays multiple fragments from a menu in the activity. I would like to assign certain methods in my activity as event handlers to certain actions in the fragments in the following pattern.

```
 public class MainActivity : FragmentActivity
 {
   protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction().Replace(Resource.Id.mainFrame,new Accountactivity()).Commit();
        SupportFragmentManager.ExecutePendingTransactions();
    }
   void MenuClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
 }
 public class AccountFragment : Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment
 {
    public override void OnResume ()
    {
        base.OnResume ();
        accountMenu.Click += ((MainActivity)Activity).MenuAccountClicked;
    }
 }
```

Will this pattern create a cyclic reference to my activity and stop the Fragment being collected by Garbage collector ?

Answer (score 3):

For this pattern you should be using [`onAttach`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onAttach%28android.app.Activity%29) and [`onDetach`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onDetach%28%29) to assign and remove your events handlers.

Assign the event handler in `onAttach` and remove it in `onDetach`.

Comment: Hi, @jimi312 I will move that to OnAttach and OnDetach. I am doing this basically to set navigation. I want to change fragments in mainActivity from  child Fragment. Is this the correct method for that ?                                            And my original question was will that create a cyclic reference in C# ? Please answer that too...

Comment: As long as you remove the event handler in onDetach, there shouldn't be  issues with cyclic references. I've used similar patterns in the past for changing fragments(using Java rather than C#) without issues.

Comment: Thank You @jimi312. In Java we can populate supply an adapter to ListActivity using ArrayAdapter safely. But in C#(when doing it with monodroid) that creates a cyclic reference. Instead we have to implement BaseAdapter<T>. I would like to know if anything like this happens when I subscribe to event handlers in the above mentioned format as I am trying to invoke a method on the base class of the fragment causing a cyclic reference.